# Scala Array to String, Map[String,Any]

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I've a scala array **"visitedArray"** with values as following:

```
Array(
    (Map(url -> http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/abc), Map(visited -> true)), 
    (Map(url -> http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/random-blog), Map(visited -> true)), 
    (Map(url -> http://www.livestream.com/forum/1),Map(visited -> false))
    ....
```

However, I want to convert it to String, Map[String,Any] and want the results to appear like:

```
(
    (http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/kate-beckett, Map(visited -> true),  
    (http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/random-blog), Map(visited -> true)
    ....
```

I've tried:

```
val testRdd = sc.parallelize(visitedArray)
val formatedRdd = testRdd.map(t => (t._1("url"), t._2))
```

However, it doesn't returns the required format. It returns:

```
Array(
    (http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/kate-beckett, Map(visited -> true),  
    (http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/random-blog), Map(visited -> true)
    ....
```

How can I achieve what I want ( convert to String, Map[String,Any] without the **Array(**)?

Comment: Do you want an Array or an RDD?

Comment: I want the array transformed to RDD. ->
Array to [String, Map[String,Any]]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you need Spark here. Are you getting these values  from some other RDD?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting these values from RDD. I've million of values like these. The above is just an example.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are getting the correct output. I formatted your question and all I see is `Array(` vs `(`

Comment: Actually, I want the results without the Array. I want them as: 
((http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/kate-beckett, Map(visited -> true),  
    (http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/random-blog), Map(visited -> true)
    ....

Comment: So, you want a `Tuple`, not an `Array` at all. You are seeing Scala's representation of the object, which will print as `Array()`

Comment: Maybe I wasn't so clear earlier, but I want an RDD[String, Map[String,Any]] or RDD[String, Map[String,Boolean]]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want this

```
  val a = Array(
    (Map("url" -> "http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/abc"), Map("visited" -> true)), 
    (Map("url" -> "http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/random-blog"), Map("visited" -> true)), 
    (Map("url" -> "http://www.livestream.com/forum/1"),Map("visited" -> false)))

  a.map {  
    case (m1: Map[String, String], m2: Map[String, Boolean]) =>
      (m1("url"), m2)
  }
```

Which results in this

```
Array(
  ("http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/abc", Map("visited" -> true)),
  ("http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/random-blog", Map("visited" -> true)),
  ("http://www.livestream.com/forum/1", Map("visited" -> false))
): Array[(String, Map[String, Boolean])]
```

And you can then `sc.parallelize` that

You only see `Array` at the beginning because that is how Scala prints the object. It's not actually "part of the data"

For example, using a `List`

```
  a.map {  
    case (m1: Map[String, String], m2: Map[String, Boolean]) =>
      (m1("url"), m2)
  } toList

List(
  ("http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/abc", Map("visited" -> true)),
  ("http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/random-blog", Map("visited" -> true)),
  ("http://www.livestream.com/forum/1", Map("visited" -> false))
): scala.package.List[(String, Map[String, Boolean])]
```

Comment: I need something like val newRdd:(String, Map[String,Boolean]) = a.map { case (a: Map[String, String], b: Map[String,Boolean]) =>
      (a("url"), b)
  } but this doesn't work because 
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Map[String,Boolean])
required: (String, Map[String,Boolean])

Comment: You are confusing Spark API with Scala... For `a.map` to return an RDD, then 1) `a` must be an RDD itself 2) You need to return an RDD within the `map` operation